# How can I build an XCode project using standard C++ library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm trying to write several `iOS` stuff, but I gave myself a challenge that to combine `XCode` and `C++`, so I need some way to build an `XCode` project with `C++`, how can I do it?

Comment: You might to look on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725850/learning-to-compile-in-xcode)

Comment: @Cro: I'm confused. You are wanting to build an `Xcode` project in `C++`, create a `C++` Xcode project, or use `C++` in Xcode — can you clarify which?

Comment: Use C++ to build project into an app.